# tomcat atomikos hibernate NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, atomikos

Hope to get an appropriate advice from you to solve my problem as i wasn't able to fix this bug for several days.
I have embedded tomcat and trying to work with JTA transactions. However, when i am trying to use my DAO class, i get NullPointerException.

I tried to follow this article: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-jta-multiple-resource-transactions-in-tomcat-with-atomikos-example.html

Here is my **Controller**:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "student")
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
StudentService studentService;

public StudentController() {

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{id}/pass/{testId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
Response getCurrentTest(@PathVariable("id") String id,@PathVariable("testId") String testId){
    TestDTO testDTO = studentService.getCurrentTest(id,testId);

    return Response.status(200).entity(testDTO).build();


}
```

}

Here is my **spring-context.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bionic"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="com.bionic.quiz" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="HSQL"/>
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction">
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"
      depends-on="atomikosTransactionManager,atomikosUserTransaction">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean"
      init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName">
        <value>DataSource</value>
    </property>
    <property name="xaDataSourceClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</value>
    </property>
    <property name="xaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="databaseName">quizzes</prop>
            <prop key="serverName">localhost</prop>
            <prop key="port">3306</prop>
            <prop key="user">root</prop>
            <prop key="password">1</prop>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizzes</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee>

<display-name>BQP</display-name>

<!--Spring-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL DS</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DataSource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>


<!--/Spring-->
```

Here is what i get when debugging my project:

[image]

in chrome:

[image]

end finally my **log file**, i will post it as a picture because i have problem with formatting here:

[image]

Also, i think, the **problem is here**, i have several warings before exceptions:

```
WARNING: atomikos connection proxy for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4ConnectionWrapper@c20ee4: WARNING: transaction manager not running?
```